# Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

actualmente tengo un nuevo error, resulta cuando ingreso a los links de las ID'S de mis productos por ejemplo:

> localhost/producto.php?id=10

Me lanza el siguiente error:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match
> number of parameters in prepared statement in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\database\db.php on line 20

Y no se muestra el producto seleccionado, se queda estancado en el mismo en todas las IDS que selecciono por ejemplo:

> localhost/producto.php?id=10 | Mayonesa
>
> localhost/producto.php?id=11 | Mayonesa
>
> localhost/producto.php?id=12 | Mayonesa

En todas las ID'S me muestra el producto de Mayonesa en vez del suyo en la base de datos. Por ejemplo la ID: 11 le pertenece a bebida.

Si no me equivoco este error se produce en la función de SelectOne ubicada en mi *DB.php* pero necesito insertar los JOINS y la única manera que consigo es esta, sin embargo me lanza el error.

El error se produce en esta línea:

```
if($table == "posts"){
      $sql = "SELECT t1.*, t2.name as tipo FROM posts AS t1 LEFT JOIN tipo as t2 ON (t1.tipo_id = t2.id)";
```

¿Alguien me puede ayudar a solucionarlo?

**POSTS.PHP**

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $post = selectOne($table, ['id' => $id]);
}
```

**DB.PHP**

```
<?php

session_start();
require('connect.php');

function dd($value)
{
    echo "<pre>", print_r($value, true), "</pre>";
    die();
}


function executeQuery($sql, $data)
{
    global $conn;
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $values = array_values($data);
    $types = str_repeat('s', count($values));
    var_dump($sql);
    var_dump($data);
    $stmt->bind_param($types, ...$values);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt;
}


function selectAll($table, $conditions = [])
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table";
            if($table == "posts"){
        $sql = "SELECT t1.*, t2.name as tipo FROM posts AS t1 LEFT JOIN tipo as t2 ON (t1.tipo_id = t2.id)";
        
        } 


    
    if (empty($conditions)) {
        $sql = $sql . " ORDER BY id DESC";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $records = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        return $records;    
    } else {
        
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($conditions as $key => $value) {
            if ($i === 0){
                $sql = $sql . " WHERE $key=?";
                
            } else {
                $sql = $sql . " AND $key=?"; 
            }
            $i++;
        }
        
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $values = array_values($conditions);
        $types = str_repeat('s', count($values));
        $stmt->bind_param($types, $values);
        $stmt->execute();
        $records = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        return $records;
    }
}



function selectOne($table, $conditions)
{
   
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table ";

        $i = 0;
                foreach ($conditions as $key => $value) {
                    
            if ($i === 0){
                $sql = $sql . " WHERE $key=?";
                
            } else {
               $sql = $sql . " AND $key=?"; 
            }
            $i++;
        }
    
        $sql = $sql . " LIMIT 1";
    
           if($table == "posts"){
    $sql = "SELECT t1.*, t2.name as tipo FROM posts AS t1 LEFT JOIN tipo as t2 ON (t1.tipo_id = t2.id)";
    
    } 
    
        $stmt = executeQuery($sql, $conditions);

        $records = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        return $records;
    
    }

function create($table, $data)
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $table SET ";
      
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            if ($i === 0){
                $sql = $sql . " $key=?";
                
            } else {
                $sql = $sql . ", $key=?"; 
            }
            $i++;
        }
    $stmt = executeQuery($sql, $data);
    $id = $stmt->insert_id;
    return $id;
    
}

function update($table, $id, $data)
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "UPDATE $table SET ";
      
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            if ($i === 0){
                $sql = $sql . " $key=?";
                
            } else {
                $sql = $sql . ", $key=?"; 
            }
            $i++;
        }
    
    $sql = $sql . " WHERE id=?";
    $data['id'] = $id;
    $stmt = executeQuery($sql, $data);
    return $stmt->affected_rows;
    
}


function delete($table, $id)
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "DELETE FROM $table WHERE id=?";
      
    $stmt = executeQuery($sql, ['id' => $id]);
    return $stmt->affected_rows;
    
}


function getPostsByTopicId($topic_id){
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE topic_id=?";
    $sql = $sql . " ORDER BY id DESC";
    $stmt = executeQuery($sql, ['topic_id' => $topic_id]);
    $records = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    return $records;
}
```

Mensaje al agregar: var_dump($sql); | var_dump($data);

> string(90) "SELECT t1.*, t2.name as tipo FROM posts AS t1 LEFT JOIN
> tipo as t2 ON (t1.tipo_id = t2.id)" array(1) { ["id"]=> string(3)
> "169" } Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables
> doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\app\database\db.php on line 22

Comment: El error es en la línea `20` del archivo `db.php`, haz un `echo` de la instrucción SQL que estás intentando preparar ahí, si es la instrucción SQL que muestras, la misma no tiene marcadores para usar `bind_param`, puede que el error sea ese.

Comment: @A.Cedano disculpa y en ese caso que puedo hacer, la verdad no entendí muy bien a lo que te refieres.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la línea 20 de `db.php`?

Comment: @A.Cedano | La línea 20 de db.php es está | $stmt->bind_param($types, ...$values);

Comment: Haz una depuración antes de esa línea poniendo esto: `var_dump($sql);` y también `var_dump($data);` y dinos qué muestra.

Comment: @A.Cedano Actualice la pregunta agregando lo que me muestra, es lo ultimo que agregue.

Comment: Esta sería tu consulta: `SELECT t1.*, t2.name as tipo FROM posts AS t1 LEFT JOIN tipo as t2 ON (t1.tipo_id = t2.id)`, si observas bien, eso no es una consulta preparada. Las mismas llevan marcadores (`?`)  para indicar las partes donde van datos que luego pasarás con `bind_param`. A eso me refería en mi primer comentario. No sé si ahora entiendes lo que quiero decirte o aún no.

Comment: @A.Cedano Si ahora entiendo y que podria hacer en este caso?

Comment: Supongo que el `id` que pasas en `$data` es porque quieres usarlo como criterio en tu consulta. ¿Es así? Si es así, ¿a cuál de las tablas pertenece esa columna y cómo se llama exactamente esa columna en la tabla?

Comment: @A.Cedano Tengo 2 tablas que quiero relacionar con JOIN, las cuales son "posts" y "tipo" | la columna "tipo_id" le pertenece a la tabla de "posts" y la columna "id" le pertenece a la tabla de "tipo"

Comment: Ya, pero yo quiero saber para qué estás pasando `$data` a esa función, ¿me explico? Tú estás pasando aparte de `$sql` este parámetro: `$data`, que es un array con algo así: `"id" => 169`, lo que pregunto es para qué es ese parámetro, si es para usarlo como criterio de la consulta SQL con un `WHERE` o si es para otra cosa.

Comment: Esa función por así decirlo la tengo global, me refiero a que actúa en mas de una sola tabla (no se como explicarme), por ejemplo también en "categorías" | he intentado crear otra función para realizar que este JOIN solamente actué en los posts pero no consigo hacerlo.

Comment: Entiendo que quieras reutilizar tu función, pero **una cosa es una consulta preparada y otra cosa es una consulta sin preparar**. En esa función se intenta usar una consulta preparada que no es tal. Además, lo que estoy preguntando, para ver si entiendo el asunto, es ¿para qué pasas el parámetro `$data` a la función? Generalmente, cuando declaras parámetros opcionales los declaras como `null` por defecto y luego dentro de la función verificas si los mismos existen o no para pasarlos.

Comment: Oh ya veo, pues la verdad creo que no hace nada. Al menos en este caso porque lo removí y no sufrió ningún efecto al no pasar $data, este lo agregue hace tiempo que tenia un duda y realice un post donde solo me dijeron que lo agregara y no me explicaron el porque.

Comment: La cuestión no es quitar `$data`  o no quitarlo, sino, ¿para qué estás pasando `$data` a la función? Estoy preguntando esto tratando de entender el problema, pero sobre todo para que entiendas tu propio código. Si lo estabas pasando es porque necesitabas filtrar algo, supongo ¿? Si debe quitarse y no necesitas filtrar nada, entonces el `bind_param` no tiene sentido en esa función. Dicho de otro modo, ¿qué es lo que quieres hacer realmente en tu código: buscar todos los registros, buscar ciertos registros basándote el algún criterio (cuál criterio y en cuál de las tablas)? ...

Comment: @A.Cedano Si no me equivoco esta buscando ciertos registros en la base de datos, en este caso post. Busca lo que pertenece a cada fila y la muestra en el ID correspondiente. Por ejemplo localhost/producto/product.php?id=14 me esta mostrando lo que le corresponde a esa ID "nombre del producto, información, etc". Lo que quiero hacer con el código actualmente es que mediante JOIN me muestre que tipo ("tipo") de producto es en su ID.

Comment: No entendí del todo, pero supongo que en ese caso tienes que ponerle un filtro a la consulta: `... WHERE laTabla.laColumnaDelId = ? ` ahí tienes el marcador del que hablaba antes, el cual será asumido en `bind_param`

Comment: @A.Cedano ¡Muchísimas gracias!, de verdad me has ayudado muchísimo, cada publicación que hago estas tu para ayudar jaja. Intentare solucionar mi error actual que es no entender mi propio código... Pero de veras muchísimas gracias.

Comment: Me alegro si te ha servido de algo. Y, cualquier duda puedes seguir preguntando a través de nuevas preguntas, siempre habrá alguien que te echará una mano. Saludos.